# Update Tab in Chrome Extension And Wait Till It opened to open another download link. How to wait till url is opened in the tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to open 100 links one by one and wait till each one is opened so that i can download data from it. How to wait till URL is opened in the tab?

```
    function downloadreport()
    { 
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab)
        {
            var reportlink=tab.url;
            looplink=tab.url.slice(0,tab.url.length-1);
            var indexcode=reportlink.indexOf('code')
            reportlink=reportlink.slice(0,indexcode+4)+"/getReport.php";
            var i;
            for (i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: looplink+i});
                /*

                How To Wait Here Till Tab Is Opened


                */
               chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: reportlink});
            }
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',downloadreport);
    });
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How to wait till tab is updated??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [WebExtension polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill), [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) listener:

```
async function downloadreport() { 
  const [tab] = await browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  let reportLink = tab.url.slice(0, tab.url.indexOf('code') + 4) + '/getReport.php';
  let loopLink = tab.url.slice(0, -1);
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    await goToUrl(tab, loopLink + i);
    await goToUrl(tab, reportLink);
  }
}

function goToUrl(tab, url) {
  browser.tabs.update(tab.id, {url});
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function onUpdated(tabId, info) {
      if (tabId === tab.id && info.status === 'complete') {
        browser.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}
```