# I am trying to make a chrome extension to open a tab then run through a list of URLs, opening the next one in each tab sequentially as they load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, time, google-chrome-extension

I do not have much formal programming knowledge, I've never taken a course and all the projects I've done so far have been simple executions of code I've slapped together and hit until it worked. I think I will be able to code it on my own so I am mainly asking for logic/structure help here.

Here is the question: I want to make a chrome extension that will open page A, wait for it to completely load + 2 seconds, then redirect to page B, wait for it to completely load + 2 seconds, then redirect to page C, etc. The user will just go AFK while it runs. I expect this list to be a few hundred URLs long, how do I structure this so I don't have like 300 functions updating the URL property to the next URL?

The two ideas I have are

```
create tab as the selected tab with URL A
onLoad wait for 2 additional seconds then update URL A to URL B
onLoad wait for 2 additional seconds of URL B update URL B to URL C
Repeat for the rest of the URLs
```

and

```
have 'file' in extension folder with a list of all URLs
create tab as the selected tab
update URL to 1st URL in 'file'
onLoad wait for 2 additional seconds then update to 2nd URL in 'file'
onLoad wait for 2 additional seconds then update to 3rd URL in 'file'
Repeat for the rest of the URLs
```

I know javascript has some weird synchronous/async stuff with executing functions and time constraints, and I'm not totally sure how it works. I would be really grateful for some input on what I would need to do to make this code work or what approach would be a better practice.

Thank you!

Comment: Use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453928/) as a base. In your case the second `await goToUrl.....` will be `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000))` and you won't need the code for reporting.

Comment: @wOxxOm , thanks for pointing me to this answer! It looks very helpful but as I'm pretty unfamiliar with javascript in general it's hard for me to understand what each part does. can you explain what `loopLink` and `tab.url.slice` do and how `goToUrl` interacts with `downloadreport`? I know that's a lot, sorry, just trying to wrap my head around how this works.